# Adding an extra point in a ggplot2 graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a plot of the Sepal.Length and the Sepal.Width (using the iris dataset) with ggplot2.

```
  ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, col = Species)) + geom_point()
```

Works fine but now I would like to add a seperate point to the graph with a blue color. So for example:

```
  df = data.frame(Sepal.Width = 5.6, Sepal.Length = 3.9)
```

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Add another layer:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, col = Species)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(aes(x=5.6, y=3.9), colour="blue")
```

Comment: I suspect this plots as many points in the same location as the amount of points being plotted. I had 7.1 million integers, and this slowed the plot generation down by about 30 seconds compared to `annotate`! Trying this with `geom_text` slowed it down more, with the text constantly flickering, as if being redrawn.

Answer (score 18):

Using *annotate*:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, col = Species)) + 
  geom_point() +
  annotate("point", x = 5.6, y = 3.9, colour = "blue")
```

Answer (score 16):

```
library('ggplot2')

df = data.frame(Sepal.Width = 5.6, Sepal.Length = 3.9) 

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, col = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = df, col = 'blue')
```

[image]