# Max values for three plots in one graph in software R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, max

I have a graph with three plots. I made them with the package ggplot2.

1. I want to calculate to what time the three plots reach the same value of X C using R programming.
2. I want also want to mark the point on the graph e.g. with a longitudinal dashed line from the x-axis.

I tried to use which.max, but it only gives me one value for one of the plots that reach plateau first. I want the the time-value where all plots reach 37 C at the same time.

Comment: can you give us some data, thus we are able to provide you some code. In general you can filter your data like df$Temerature >= 37 and then select the lowest timepoints by Stat groups.

Comment: Now it is attached :)

Comment: Please don't share data as images, it useless for all [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11374827).

Comment: @Sarah please post the output of `dput(My_data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, which gives you the index of the first time they are all equal to 37:

```r
# generate example data
x <- c(3:37, rep(37,3))
y <- c(5:37, rep(37,5))
z <- c(7:37, rep(37,7))

# first instance when all are equal to 37
min(which(x == 37 & y == 37 & z ==37))
#> [1] 35
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem. How can I show this point on the plot using a dashed line?

Comment: I assume you mean vertical dashed line. You can add  `+ geom_vline(xintercept = 35, linetype = 2)`

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to add the value 35 also on the plot?

Comment: `+ annotate ("point", x = 35, y = 37)`. Also see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36541086/adding-an-extra-point-in-a-ggplot2-graph